# SQL Server 2008 data loss with CE replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-ce, replication

I am using SQL Server 2008 CE replication, and seem to be suffering some data loss (i.e. records are not appearing on the CE databases after a full sync).

I am getting the following entries in the application log:

Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0033007B-0043-0039-4400-440036003300 failed. Internal error: A read operation from the device or the IIS server returned an incorrect number of bytes while trying to process a synchronization request. [,,,,,]

Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0045007B-0038-0037-3200-430036004200 failed. Internal error: Either the computer running IIS is out of memory or an incorrect session ID was sent in a request. [Session id,,,,,]

Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0033007B-0043-0039-4400-440036003300 failed. Validation of table row counts failed. Try resynchronizing. [,,,,,]

Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0043007B-0036-0044-4400-320032003000 failed. The merge process could not initialize the subscription. Ensure that the subscription registration exists at the publisher, and reregister the subscription if necessary.

Replication-Replication Merge Subsystem: agent 0036007B-0037-0042-4500-370036003600 failed. Authentication failed on the computer running IIS. [,,,,,]

The messages seem to indicate that IIS is running out of RAM. It's using around 22 MB, and W3WP is using around 70 MB. SQL Server have consumed most of the remaining 4 GB of RAM. There is plenty of disk space. These error occur every few hours in the event log.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Add more RAM to the machine has helped the problem, (and the out of memory exceptions have gone) however, I'm still having problems.

It seems to take a very long time for some users to run a 'data validation' task on the database prior to syncronization (I'm talking > 20 mins) which I might be contributing to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this exact error. The actual problem was the IIS Pool timeout! So, the larger the database the slower and slower the client is to process until it takes the device more then 20 minutes to process which causes the Pool session to timeout so that when the next request comes it the backend chokes. So, one option is to increase the timeout. BUT!! The solution I used was to increase the process buffer on the client side as described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/06/24/performance-tips-for-faster-download-of-a-large-sql-compact-3-5-database-via-replication.aspx

Here is my post when I was working thru this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9414df5-f066-450c-8e26-6f4c62a3897a/iis-replication-agent-restarts-replication-never-finishes

Also one interesting thought is you can do the merge on a PC once and then deploy that file to the devices, obviously may not fit your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up on solving the problem, and abandoned SQL Mobile Replication in favour of implementing my own sync interface using web services :¬(